# How to get Dataframe from foreach loop?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, foreach, apache-spark-sql

I have to **iterate** DataFrame using **foreach** and i need **Dataframe** as output.

```
val tt = df.foreach { 
  df
}
```

Comment: You're probably implementing the wrong solution here (they call this [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) around here). What do you want to do with `df` in the lambda?

Comment: hi, i have to iterate my dataframe and after some logic i have to do UnionAll of the result which i want return from foreach.

Comment: May be post it with some examples on what you want to do with Input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` won't return anything, it is used for taking an action based on each row of a dataframe. You should use `.map` which will return a modified dataframe which you can union all with other df having same schema.

```
val tt1 = df.map(action(_))
val df = tt1.union(tt2)
```